# Why I can't install rails with gem install rails -v 4.0.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I have installed on GNU/Linux:

> rvm 1.23.16 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]
>   ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]

I apparently have all gems in my system, but when I run the command: `gem install rails -v 4.0.0` it states that one gem was installed. But Rails isn't installed yet.

When I use `gem install rails -v 4.0.0` or `gem install rails --version=4.0`
occurs that:

```
Parsing documentation for rails-4.0.0
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/belongs_to.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xF4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/book_icon.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x91" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/bullet.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\xF5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/chapters_icon.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\xF5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/check_bullet.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\xF4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/credits_pic_blank.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/csrf.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/edge_badge.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x9E" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/favicon.ico, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/feature_tile.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/footer_tile.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/fxn.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/challenge.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/confirm_dialog.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/forbidden_attributes_for_new_post.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/form_with_errors.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/index_action_with_edit_link.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/new_post.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/post_with_comments.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/rails_welcome.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/routing_error_no_controller.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/routing_error_no_route_matches.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/show_action_for_posts.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/template_is_missing_posts_new.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/undefined_method_post_path.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/unknown_action_create_for_posts.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/getting_started/unknown_action_new_for_posts.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xF0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/grey_bullet.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/habtm.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/has_many.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/has_many_through.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/has_one.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/has_one_through.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/header_backdrop.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/header_tile.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_html_safe.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_localized_pirate.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_translated_en.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_translated_pirate.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_translation_missing.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_untranslated.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/1.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/10.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/11.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/12.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/13.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/14.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/15.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/2.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/3.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/4.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/5.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/6.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/7.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/8.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/9.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/caution.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/example.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/home.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/important.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/next.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/note.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/prev.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/tip.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/up.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/icons/warning.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/jaimeiniesta.jpg, skipping
unable to convert "\xF5" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/nav_arrow.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/oscardelben.jpg, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/polymorphic.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/radar.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/rails4_features.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/rails_guides_kindle_cover.jpg, skipping
unable to convert "\xEC" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/rails_guides_logo.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x8C" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/rails_logo_remix.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/session_fixation.png, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_grey.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_info.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_note.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_red.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_yellow.gif, skipping
unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/tab_yellow.png, skipping
unable to convert "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/vijaydev.jpg, skipping
1 gem installed
```

How I can install Rails 4.0.0 using RVM?

Comment: How do you know “Rails isn’t installed yet”?

Comment: +1 & what does `rails -v` show?

Comment: what does `gem list` show. and `which gem` are you using?

Comment: Well, rails -v shows that the packages rails doesn't installed. And give the trivial suggestion of install using apt-get install rails. But this way not make sense if I want use rvm and specific gem for rails 4.0.0.

Comment: Can you check if `gem install rails --version=4.0` works and let us know?

Comment: @ansh0l this commang give me messages similar to this: unable to convert "\x89" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for guides/assets/images/belongs_to.png, skipping.

Comment: @LeandroArruda If that's the error you get, can you add the full error trace to your question?

Comment: Well folks, I resolved but of a shape of very experimental. I did re-install of all gems necessary for the work of Rails, individualized, and not concatenated, although any error occurred before. I will look better the answer of @carols10cents because appears be very solid the points exposed for her

Comment: In the beginning I was installing Rails 4.0.0 in Elementary Luna OS. Then, I installed of the same mode on Debian 7.2 and Ubuntu 12.04, just with the suggestion @carols10cents: increase of parameter for don't install the documentation in the same process of Rails installation. Apparently the Elementary Luna have some incompatibility with this version of Rails (maybe) or, probably, particularly my system is crashed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These error messages are being created while the Rails documentation is being installed on your machine. I found two Rails issues discussing this: [#9590](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9590) and [#11814](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11814).

This is ultimately [an issue with rdoc and ruby 2.0](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc/issues/189) that was [fixed](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc/commit/ceb81dd11911fb8a1f7342f5710f6afdd2036fc7) but isn't in a released version of rdoc yet.

There are a few ways to get around this, I'm listing them in the order I would probably try them:

1. Don't install the documentation with the rails gem; instead of running `gem install rails` do `gem install rails --no-rdoc --no-ri`. I hardly ever use built in documentation anyway, so I actually have `gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc` in my `~/.gemrc` file so that documentation is never installed for any gem.
2. Install rails without documentation as in #1, but then build the documentation by hand using rdoc and the `--exclude='.dat'` flag, like `rdoc --exclude='.dat' activesupport/lib` to build the activesupport docs, [as recommended in this comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9590#issuecomment-14561135).
3. Install rdoc from github at a commit that is later than [ceb81dd11](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc/commit/ceb81dd11911fb8a1f7342f5710f6afdd2036fc7). Using bundler's `git` or `github` options in your Gemfile make this easy, but there must be other reasons that a new version hasn't been released yet, so there might be bugs.

Comment: I will look soon about your considerations with care, because I resolved que but the shape of very experimental. In the moment I can say that I did re-install of all gems necessary for the work of Rails, individualized, and not concatenated, although any error occurred before.

Comment: You are right about the methods of separate the installation of rails and the documentation. It will be useful for me from now on, thanks. However, I still haven't success the simple task of installing the rails. The commands run, show that one gem was installed, but any version of rails make part of my environment. Very weird.

Comment: I'd recommend starting a new question describing what you're seeing now that you're past the errors. I suspect there's something going on with your PATH, rvm, rvm gemsets, bundler, or your system ruby...

Comment: I installed of the same mode on Debian 7.2 and Ubuntu 12.04, just with you suggestion increase of parameter for don't install the documentation in the same process of Rails installation:> gem install rails -v 4.0.0 --no-rdoc --no-ri. Thanks by your attention.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this a lot working with new rails users, and often what people miss is restarting the terminal (or whatever shell) after the install. ***The fact that you saw a gem get installed but couldn't find it directly after might be a symptom.*** (Know its an old post but trying to help alleviate pain.)

Answer (score -2):

run this command

```
$ . ~/.bash_profile
```

after rvm install

Comment: That was done. I think that I will need show step by step my instalation.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with rvm.

Comment: @carols10cents When you install ever appears the all lines informing unable to convert beetwen ASCII and the character pattern UTF?

Comment: @VitaliyKrushelnitsky This is justly the content I used like base. The methods which Carol exposed are precise for fix problem with documentation.